# OpenCl 2: How to convert image2d object to buffer without copy and vice versa

Tags: buffer, opencl, gpgpu

Does anyone know how to convert a given image2d object into buffer, and from buffer to image2d object?

I know that in opencl 1.2 there was an extension called cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer, and that in opencl 2 it became core functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Use cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer when you can, otherwise write a kernel that copies the data from image to buffer or buffer to image. The memory layout of an image is private to the implementation and should be considered unknown.